# How to control the timing when changing layouts in android apps?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

My goal is to create a sort of animation, by controlling the timing when changing layouts.

Thats what I tried:

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);

try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);

try{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.third_screen);

try{
    Thread.sleep(1200);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.forth_screen);

try{
    Thread.sleep(800);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.fifth_screen);

try{
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch(Exception e){}

setContentView(R.layout.sixth_screen);
```

But it's not working properly, because the last layout is chosen, and the others skipped.

Answer (score 0):

One method to perform an action after a predefined delay is using a `Handler`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do stuff here
                setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

Code in `run()` will be executed after a 3 seconds delay. To repeat this for each of your screens, define this method:

```
private void delayedSetContentView(final int viewId, int delay) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(viewId);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

And then in `onCreate()`:

```
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.first_screen, 3000);
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.second_screen, 1000);
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.third_screen, 500);
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.fourth_screen, 1200);
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.fifth_screen, 800);
delayedSetContentView(R.layout.sixth_screen, 500);
```